# How to merge different time-series plot into a 2D in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, time-series

I have three different time-series data of the following format where the first column is timestamp and the second column is the value.

```
0.086206438,10
0.086425551,12
0.089227066,20
0.089262508,24
0.089744425,30
0.090036815,40
0.090054172,28
0.090377569,28
0.090514071,28
0.090762872,28
0.090912691,27
```

For reproduciability, I have shared the three time-series data I am using [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CoTiB3Tg_722OTc7Hum3hYOB3LLpfg7c).

From column 2, I wanted to read current row and compare it with the value of the previous row. If it is greater, I keep comparing. If the current value is smaller than the previous row's value continue, I take the difference. Let me make it clear. For example in the above sample record I provided, the seventh row (28) is smaller than the value in the sixth row (40) - so it will be (40-28 =12).

Here is my sample code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import norm
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf, acf


protocols = {}


types = {"data1": "data1.csv", "data2": "data2.csv", "data3": "data3.csv"}

for protname, fname in types.items():
    arr = []  
    arr1 = []  
    with open(fname, mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
        for i in reader:
            arr.append(int(i[1])) 
            arr1.append(float(i[0])) 

    arr, arr1 = np.array(arr), np.array(arr1)
    diffs = np.diff(arr)
    diffs1 = np.diff(arr1)
    diffs1 = diffs1[diffs > 0] 
    diffs = diffs[diffs > 0] # To keep only the increased values
    protocols[protname] = {
        "rtime": np.array(arr1),
        "rdata": np.array(arr),
        "data": diffs,
        "timediff": diffs,
    }

## change in time 
for protname, values in protocols.items():
    d = values["rdata"]
    t = values["rtime"]
    d = np.diff(d, 1) #/ d[:-1]
    t = np.diff(t, 1)
    plt.plot(t, d, ".", label=protname, alpha=0.5)
    plt.xlabel("Changes in time")
    plt.ylabel("differences")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

This gives me the following plots

[image]
[image]
[image]

How can we plot the differences versus the change in time (column onw) in a two-dimensitional (2D) graph of the three data I included separately?

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you're asking for? Do you want the three graphs in one?

Comment: Yeah three of them in one but in a 2D by ignoring the positive values on the `Y-axis` (differences).

Comment: So you want those three data sets on the same plot as different series? Or you want a different kind of graph entirely?

Comment: Did you try to simply unindent `plt.show()`? So that you do not show each single plot within the loop, but show all three together when the loop is finished?

Comment: @SpghttCd, yes I did but I don't wan the positive values in Y-axis to be included.

Comment: @WilliamMiller, I just want to plot those three datas according the requirement I mentioned in my question. Thanks

Comment: So three data series on one set of axes without the negative y-values? Or am I still missing something?

Comment: @WilliamMiller, without the positive (+ve) values in the Y-axis

Comment: Does it suffice to restrict the limits of the plot or do you want the positive values filtered out of the array entirely?

Comment: @WilliamMiller, Yes, I want to filter out the positive values out of the array. I only want to consider when the value at a row drops. The positive values are for the increasing part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the loop

```
for protname, values in protocols.items():
    d = values["rdata"]
    t = values["rtime"]
    d = np.diff(d, 1) #/ d[:-1]
    t = np.diff(t, 1)
    plt.plot(t, d, ".", label=protname, alpha=0.5)
    plt.xlabel("Changes in time")
    plt.ylabel("differences")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

to

```
for protname, values in protocols.items():
    d = values["rdata"]
    t = values["rtime"]
    d = np.diff(d, 1) #/ d[:-1]
    t = np.diff(t, 1)
    plt.plot(t[d < 0], d[d < 0], ".", label=protname, alpha=0.5)
    plt.xlabel("Changes in time")
    plt.ylabel("differences")
    plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

You will get a plot that looks like
[image: Filtered plot]

I believe this is what you are looking for - if I understood you correctly.

Comment: Exactly adn I have made your answer as accepted. Thank you so much. I am looking for ways to classify these patterns. As you can see, it seems to be not easy to know which point belongs to which data. Do you see any good technique to classify time-series data like this? You can easily see the pattern when you plot the raw data I shared.

Answer (score 1):

All three plots into one: unindent `plt.show()`

Plot only the negative values of an array:

```
plt.plot(t[d<0], d[d<0], ...)
```

Comment: thank you. How about if we wnat to take the average of differences for each data?

Comment: you're welcome - I don't quite understand. The differences are `d`, right? So the average is `np.mean(d)`. Do you wonder how to plot that? You could add a horizontal line (`plt.hlines(np.mean(d), np.min(t), np.max(t))`) or if you're generally more interested in a statistical view on your data, perhaps consider using e.g. [boxplots](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html).

Comment: But I want `np.mean(d)` of each data separatly. If we do `plt.hlines(np.mean(d), np.min(t), np.max(t))` - it combines the mean of the three data I shared in one which makes is hard to compare (classify) the three data.

Comment: no, why? you calculate `d` in a loop, so `d` is not all the data but only one subset. Plotting `d` over `t` also lead to three plots, not only one for all. So the mean of it is the mean of one subset. Did you already try to add the `plt.hlines()` function in your loop?

Comment: Yeah I did that and it is plotting only one straight line. The reason why I wanted to see them separately is for classification of the data I shared with my question in case you haven't seen it.

Comment: if `d` changes while iterating over the loop, `mean(d)` should change, too, so consequentely you should definitely get three different `hlines`. Is it possible that they are so close together that they just _look_  like one single line? Or did you fix `plt.ylims()`, so that two of them maybe reside beyond the borders of your plotting range? Perhaps you can add a `print(np.mean(d))` in the loop for debugging puposes...